# No Games Installed with Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7, windows

Ordered a PC from HP with Windows 7 Professional 64-bit preinstalled, of course. No Win7 disc was included with computer. There are no games installed. I have tried to "activate" them through the Control Panel procedure, but each time I do it there is an error message telling me that not all components installed. And my Games folder is empty. Is there a solution?

Synetech asked what I meant by "activate through Control Panel." I'm referring to the "Turn windows features on" procedure that's supposed to work for everybody. I'm sure it does for most, but it didn't for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "activate them through Control Panel procedure"? Do you mean that you used the `optionalfeatures.exe` program?

Comment: @Synetech : That's accessible through Control Panel > Program options > Manage windows applications on the left panel. My translations might be poor, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can find an official ISO file (DVD image) of all the major versions of Windows 7 at this site: http://www.mydigitallife.info/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-from-digital-river/
You have to have your own key to reinstall Windows (should be on the case of the computer), but that shouldn't be necessary just to install additional features.  Download the ISO file that best matches your version of Windows and either burn it to DVD or load it with a program like [Virtual CloneDrive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html) or [DaemonTools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/products/dtLite).  Once you have the disc or image available, you should be able to install the additional features through **Control Panel** => **Programs and Features** => **Turn Windows features on or off**.

Answer (score 1):

You can request the Original DVD or ISO from Microsoft, then mount it as a virtual drive and install them.

Or you could ask a friend for the installation DVD

Comment: When booting up the machine the first time, it will also offer to create a rescue disc.

Comment: @RandolphWest - what's that got to do with installing the games?

Comment: Everything. The rescue disc includes a perfectly workable version of Windows from which to do the game installation, without needing to call a friend.